# closed continuous path in $\mathbb{C}$ homotopic to polygon

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

I've been looking for a solution of problem:

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C} $ be a open set and $\Gamma:[0,1]\to U$ is a continuous closed path (i.e. starts and ends at the same point. Then $\Gamma$ is homotopic to a polygonal path.

By definition, two closed continuous paths $\Gamma_0,\Gamma_1$ are homotopic in $U$, if there exists a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to U$ such that $\gamma(0,t)=\Gamma_0(t)$, $\gamma(1,t)=\Gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma(s,0)=\gamma(s,1)$ for every $s\in(0,1)$.

I already found some answers, but no reliable proof that works also for ugly continuous paths. I tried to do it myself:

Denote $\Gamma^{\epsilon}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C};\;dist(z,\Gamma([0,1]))<\epsilon\} $. Since $\Gamma([0,1])$ is compact and $U$ open, we see that $\Gamma^{\epsilon}\subset U$ for some $\epsilon>0$. For this $\epsilon$ by uniform continuity of $\Gamma$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|\Gamma(x)-\Gamma(y)|<\epsilon$. We divide $[0,1]$ into segments $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ where $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_n=1$ and choose $n$ large enough so $t_{i+1}-t_i<\delta$.
By the uniform continuity of $\Gamma$, if $y\in[t_i,t_{i+1}] $ then $\Gamma(y)\in B_{\epsilon}(\Gamma(t_i))\subset\Gamma^{\epsilon}\subset U$. $B_{\epsilon}(\Gamma(t_i))$ denotes the ball with radius $\epsilon$ and center at $\Gamma(t_i)$.

Now we construct a suitable polygon $\Delta:[0,1]\to\Gamma^{\epsilon} $ that satisfies our requirement. Let $i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, we set $\Delta(t_i)=\Gamma(t_i)$ - verteces of the polygon and $E_i=\Delta(t)$ be a parametrization of the edge connecting $\Delta(t_{i}), \Delta(t_{i+1})$ for $t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}] $. Then $\Delta(t_{i-1}), \Delta(t_{i+1})\in B_{\epsilon}(\Gamma(t_i))$ $(\Delta(t_{n})=\Delta(t_{0})$, i.e. $\Delta$ starts and ends at the same point) and also the corresponding edges $E_{i-1},E_i$ are subsets of the same ball. For $t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}] $ we define homotopy $\gamma(s,t)=(1-s)\Gamma(t)+s\Delta(t)$. Since $B_{\epsilon}(\Gamma(t_i))$ is convex, function $\gamma$ attains its values within this ball. Hence $\gamma:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to U$ is well defined and continuous.

I would like to know if this proof is correct or not. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.